# Displaying data from Meteor 1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

On startup I add data to meteor from a json file like this:

```
 13 if (Meteor.isServer) {
 14
 15   //startup
 16   Meteor.startup(function () {
 17     if(Plugins.find().count() === 0) {
 18       var plugins_data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('plugins_data.json'));
 19       _.each(plugins_data, function(){
 20         Plugins.insert( plugins_data );
 21         console.log('created new plugin record');
 22       });
 23     }
 24   });
 25
 26 }
```

I have a collection called `plugins` that looks like using `db.plugins.find().pretty()` in `meteor mongo` to view the data:

```
"222" : {
    "plugin-name-one" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "id" : 888,
                "title" : ""
            }
        ]
    }
},
"223" : {
    "plugin-name-two" : {
        "data" : [
            {
                "id" : 555,
                "title" : ""
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Here how I'm trying to display the data:

```
  3 if (Meteor.isClient) {
  4
  5   Template.list.helpers({
  6     list_all: function() {
  7       return Plugins.find();
  8     }
  9   });
 10
 11 }
```

and html template:

```
  5 <body>
  6   <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  7     {{> list}}
  8 </body>
  9
 10
 11 <template name='list'>
 12   {{#each list_all}}
 13     <h1>{{name}}</h1>
 14   {{/each}}
 15 </template>
```

How do I show the data from the field (and the field name) `plugin-name-1` and `plugin-name-2`  as shown from my mongo collection? I can't find any info from the docs. How do I display this data correctly?

Comment: by the way I'm using the default `autopublish` package that comes enabled in meteor by default, not using any other packages while I learn meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any pool called `name`.

Also, better way to check if there is collection created use `if(Plugins.findOne())`.

What's more, `ENUMERATE_THIS` is an object, so after rename `{{name}}` will return `[Object object]` if I remember correctly

EDIT:
OK after edit I think I know what you want to do, IMO structure should look like this

```
{
        name:"plugin_one",
        "data" : [
            {
                "id" : 888,
                "title" : ""
            }
        ]
},
 {
        name:"plugin_two",
        "data" : [
            {
                "id" : 888,
                "title" : ""
            }
        ]
},
```

And I assume you want to keep more data in one plugin, and that's why there is an array, if not structure can something like this

```
{
        name:"plugin_one",
        id : "888",
        title : ""
},
 {
        name:"plugin_two",
        id : "888",
        title : ""
},
```

and in HTML you can do something like this:

```
<template name='list'>
    {{#each list_all}}
      <h1>{{name}} {{data.id}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

or without an array

```
<template name='list'>
        {{#each list_all}}
          <h1>{{name}} {{id}}</h1>
        {{/each}}
    </template>
```

Comment: So how do I show `enumerate_this`? could you show me some example code please? I just want to show name of `enumerate_this` so that it would render `<h1> enumerate_this data 1</h1>` , `<h1> enumerate_this data 2</h1>` and so on

Comment: ENUMERATE_THIS is an object, not a string. Now that I'm not on Linux, I think `{{ENUMERATE_THIS.data.id}}` or `{{ENUMERATE_THIS.data[0].id}}` would return value

Comment: oh no so I want to show what is in the `enumerate_this` field without specifying the fieldname if you know what I mean (sorry if I had been unclear). Any suggestions?

Comment: This will most probably show `[Object object]`, but you can get to this data by simply writing `{{this}}` or `{{{this}}}`. You have to know pool names since you have to write it in html, I don't know any way to do it dynamically

Comment: Ah okay I'll check it out. Thanks for your help Sindis, I've also updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Np but I gotta ask, why do you want different pool names in db? Imo only data should be different, structure should remain the same. After edit - maybe create array named plugin-names, and inside of it create pool named number:"1"  for example

Comment: First time using mongodb, I'll take a look at this and read the mongo docs again. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer aswell, maybe now it's mroe usefull